# Generalized tight-binding model - how to solve it?

Tags: condensed-matter

Consider a generalized 1D tight-binding model (without spin) with the following Hamiltonian
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{H}\left(\{\chi_{r,r+1}\}\right)=\sum_{r}(\chi_{r,r+1}c^\dagger_rc_{r+1}+h.c.)~,
\end{equation}
and suppose that the complex number $\chi_{r,r+1}$ is a variational parameter. The $r$ index runs over a lattice sites of a 1D chain (you can think of this as a periodic boundary condition problem with $N$ lattice sites).

**Q**: Given an arbitrary set of $\chi_{r,r+1}$, is there a systematic procedure to find the ground-state of the model (numerically or analytically) ? I'm not looking for a detailed answer with the calculation here. Perhaps just a good reference or starting point. For instance, in the case where $\chi_{r,r+1}=\chi$ $\forall r$, the system can be diagonalized by a simple lattice Fourier transform.

Comment: Is this a sensible question to ask? Take any $\chi_{r,r+1}$, solve it. Then if the ground state is negative, just rescale $\chi \to \lambda \chi$ and if the ground state is positive, rescale $\chi \to -\lambda \chi$. As $\lambda \to \infty$ the ground state energy $\to -\infty$. Which is erm, minimum. What are you looking for?

Comment: Of course, when I say "minimize" this is in units of this $\chi$. Otherwise the question would not make sense as you have noted. To be more specific, take a random set of $\chi_{r,r+1}$... Now, how do you solve this, i.e. how do you find the spectrum ?

Comment: Are the particles fermions or bosons? What is the system size? How many particles are there?

Comment: These are fermions on say a $N$-site lattice. However the number of fermion depends on the choice of $\chi_{r,r+1}$.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Why the number of fermions depends on the choice of $\chi_{r,r+1}$? Are you working in the grand-canonical ensemble?

Comment: I mean that depending on the set of $\chi_{r,r+1}$, the ground-state of your Hamiltonian will change. Thus, the number of fermions forming your ground-state depends on the set of $\chi_{r,r+1}$.

Comment: I see, so you don't impose any constraint on the number of particles, and the ground state for a given $\mathcal{H}$ is obtained by filling up all negative energy states. If my understanding is correct, you can simply diagonalize the corresponding (almost) tri-diagonal matrix to find the ground state energy, which should be easy to do numerically.

Comment: Are you familiar with how to solve the $\chi_{r,r+1} = 1$ case?

Comment: @ Isidore Seville : The $\chi_{r,r+1}$ indeed forms a tridiagonal matrix, but you still have to deal with the Hilbert space spanned by the possible $\left|0\right>,\left|1\right>$ states at each site of the lattice.
@ dayareishq : yes -- in this particular case, one can diagonalize the system by doing a Fourier transform -- thanks for mentioning that, I'll add a note to the question.

Comment: The ground state of $\mathcal{H}$ is given by filling up all negative energy states. In other words, let $H$ be the first-quantized Hamiltonian corresponding to $\mathcal{H}$, then the ground state energy is $E=\mathrm{Tr}(H\Theta(-H))$.

Comment: @ Isidore Seville : What do you mean by "first quantized" ? What the relation between $\mathcal{H}$ and $H$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, it is probably a bad idea to exchange in comments. Let me expand what I said in the comments.

If my understanding is correct, the OP wants to know, as the first step toward solving the whole problem, the ground state energy of the many-body Hamiltonian $\mathcal{H}$ defined by
$$
\mathcal{H} = \sum_{r,s}H_{rs}c^\dagger_r c_{s},
$$
for a given set of parameters $\{ H_{rs}\}$. Here $c^\dagger_{r}$ and $c_{r}$ are standard fermion creation and annihilation operators. The subscripts $r,s$ run over all lattice sites from 1 to $N$. The Hermiticity requires that
$$
H_{rs} = H^\ast_{sr}.
$$
In other words, the $N\times N$ matrix $H$, whose $(r,s)$ entry is defined to be $H_{rs}$, must be Hermitian. In some literature, $H$ is known as the "first-quantized Hamiltonian". Note that the above $\mathcal{H}$ takes a slightly more general form than the one described by OP.

The first step is to diagonalize $\mathcal{H}$. To this end, we introduce a new set of fermion operators:
$$
c_{r} = \sum_{m}V_{rm}f_{m};\quad{}c^\dagger_{r}=\sum_{m}V^\ast_{rm}f^\dagger_{m}.
$$
We demand that the new fermion operators obey the standard fermion algebra. It can be seen that this is amount to demand
$$
\sum_{m}V_{rm}V^\ast_{sm}=\delta_{rs},
$$
or equivalently $VV^\dagger=1_N$, i.e. $V$ is a unitary $N\times N$ matrix.

Substituting the above in, we find $\mathcal{H}$ written in terms of new fermion operators,
$$
\mathcal{H} = \sum_{r,s,m,n}V^\ast_{rm}V_{sn}H_{rs}f^\dagger_m f_n = \sum_{m,n}(V^\dagger HV)_{mn}f^\dagger_m f_n.
$$
Since $H$ is Hermitian, we can always find a unitary $V$ so that $H$ is diagonalized:
$$
V^\dagger HV = \Lambda.
$$
Here $\Lambda = \textrm{diag}(\lambda_1,\lambda_2\cdots,\lambda_N)$. $\lambda_i\in\mathbb{R}$ are eigenvalues of $H$. Thus,
$$
\mathcal{H} = \sum_{m}\lambda_m f^\dagger_m f_m.
$$
This is the desired diagonalized form of $\mathcal{H}$.

The second step is to find the ground state energy of $\mathcal{H}$. We see that all eigenstates of $\mathcal{H}$ are labeld by the occupation numbers $f^\dagger_mf_m$. It is easy to see that the ground state of $\mathcal{H}$ is constructed by filling up all modes with negative energy. In other words, in the ground state,
$$
f^\dagger_m f_m=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
1 & \lambda_m<0\\
0 & \lambda_m>0
\end{array}
\right. .
$$
There will be degeneracy if some $\lambda_m = 0$. Then, the ground state energy is
$$
E_{G}=\sum_{m,\lambda_m<0}\lambda_m.
$$

Comment: Great ! I had not thought of this general kind of BG transformation.